# Test Flume HDFS sink and netcat source using cURL and manually adding timestamp

Tags: curl, flume

I have the following flume configuration

```
tier1.sources.source1.type     = netcat 
tier1.sources.source1.bind     = 199.9.0.11
tier1.sources.source1.port     = 9999
tier1.sources.source1.channels = channel1 
tier1.channels.channel1.type   = memory 

tier1.sinks.sink1.type         = hdfs 
tier1.sinks.sink1.channel      = channel1 
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path  = /flume/events/%y-%m-%d/%H%M/%S 
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.filePrefix = events-
```

How can I test this with cURL **manually specifying** the time stamp?

I've tried different variations of the following:

```
curl -H 'timestamp : 1471620532' --data 'test' telnet://199.9.0.11:9999
```

Everything I try ends up with errors in the Flume log:

> Expected timestamp in the Flume event headers, but it was null

All solutions to this have you have you setting hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp = true and or using an Interceptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the source does not necessarily have to be netcat, then I suggest going with [HTTP Source](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#http-source).

There you can specify any headers, other than that it could be used very similarly to the netcat source.

For an example config, you may try

```
a1.sources = r1
a1.channels = c1
a1.sources.r1.type = http
a1.sources.r1.port = 5140
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1

a1.channels = c1
a1.channels.c1.type = memory
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 10000
a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 10000
a1.channels.c1.byteCapacityBufferPercentage = 20
a1.channels.c1.byteCapacity = 800000

a1.channels = c1
a1.sinks = k1
a1.sinks.k1.type = logger
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

Comment: I ended up going with a kafka source, but yeah, getting away from the netcat source was certainly the best course of action for my use case.